# How do I merge the vertices or edges of two separate objects?

Tags: modeling, vertices

While modelling a character, I modelled the legs separates but now I want to merge both objects at the crotch area, but whenever I press "M" to merge the vertices at the crotch area I get a totally different result. It doesn't matter if I select "At Center" or "At Cursor" or anything, I still get this same result.

So here's what it looks like before pressing "M" (with the faces I want to merge being selected)
[image]

And after I press "M"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, first make sure that the 2 meshes are in the same object, select your 2 faces and use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*. Then if you want the 2 parts to merge enable the *Merge* option in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Comment: I tried, but it didn't merge for some odd reason. Here's a drive link to the file itself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19d3NlIex8wCiyCJy6q_ixLtfSGmB4U2i/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Remove the Boolean modifier of Cube.001, join Cube.001 Cube with a Ctrl J, in Edit mode recalculate the normals with Shift N, then Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> keys to scale the selected vertices to a single point - this point is the *Pivot Point*, which by default is the *Median Point* (center). You can press <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) key to bring up *Pivot Point* choice, and switch it to e.g. *3D Cursor*.

Keep in mind this will produce two vertices, one for each object. Separate objects can't share a vertex. You could merge both objects into one by selecting both and pressing <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, then merging will work…